# add recycle view item to another screen from a recycle view- kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, screen, kivymd, nestedrecyclerview

I have two screens. `MainScreen` and `Playlist`. `MainScreen` has a `RecycleView` method added that displays  list of items. These items are created from **folder names**(directories). I want the files inside each folder(directories) to open on the `Playlist` Screen depending on which directory name is clicked.

I intend to clear the screen immediately after the user leaves the screen.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

from pathlib import Path, PurePath

# Music Path
storageLocation = Path.cwd()
if Path('Books').is_dir():
    storageLocation = Path.cwd() / 'Books'

class RecycleViewRow(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()


class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        booksdir = [f for f in storageLocation.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]
        self.children[0].data = [{'text': str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in booksdir]
       # print(self.children[0].data)

class Playlist(MDScreen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.Box.clear_widgets()
        #self.ids.Box.add_widget(MDRectangleFlatButton(text="done", ))
        print(self.manager.ids)
        return


class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainScreen'))
        sm.add_widget(Playlist(name='Playlist'))
        sm.add_widget(Test(name="Test"))
        return sm  
Main().run()
```

.kv

```
<RecycleViewRow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: root.text
        #on_press: app.root.message_box(root.text)
        on_release:app.root.current = 'Playlist'

<MainScreen>:


    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'RecycleViewRow'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'


<Playlist>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id:Box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a method from your `RecycleViewRow`, like this:

```
<RecycleViewRow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: root.text
        on_release: app.fill_playlist(root.text)
```

Then, the the `fill_playlist()` method. you can fill the `PlayList`:

```
def fill_playlist(self, dir):
    self.root.current = 'Playlist'  # this also clears the play list
    playlist = self.root.get_screen('Playlist')
    for sub in os.listdir(dir):
        playlist.ids.Box.add_widget(MDRectangleFlatButton(text=sub))
```

Comment: So sorry, during tests I found something that caused the blank screen. The code works as is without changing anything. My app is almost done. @John Anderson saves the day

Comment: How can `Pathlib` give the same results. `dir.iterdir` returns gives an `str` error